# ajax autosaving on php + mysql - server load?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a question regarding autosaving of a form onto the database.
I am building a web application where changes to a form will result in an autosave onblur per field.

I am actually wondering if this is actually puts alot of strain on the server since you make many queries over a short time going through a form?

**Method 1**: when an input field is onBlur, the field triggers an update query to update the field on it's own.

**Method 2**: when a field is onBlur, the entire form is 'submitted' as a single query via ajax. (more convenient - but a longer query is made everytime a field is changed and defocused)

What are the best practices for this type of "Live" Form Editing implementation?
Would appreciate any advice!

Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend that you set a time interval for when the last save occurred, constantly saving the form would cause a concern if you have a lot of users utilizing the system.

Comment: I have thought about a fixed time interval type of saving... but would you use a $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() to do a final save before the user leaves the page then in this case?

Comment: I believe that would work fine, it triggers on a go back or exit page from what I understand.

Comment: actually, I thought you could also do without the saving intervals, and only save upon the user leaving the page? I think this will work too!

Comment: That would work as well (: it would also greatly reduce server communications.

Comment: Thanks skewled! didn't get any answers but at least you responded! :D

Comment: I decided to add this as an answer to help anyone who finds this from google or another search engine, I feel it works perfectly for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise two options:

**1.** You save the data at timed intervals, this would reduce load on the server for a very busy server.
 **2.** You would use the `$(window).bind('beforeunload', function()` jQuery function to do some last minute saving before the user leaves the page.

**Example:**

```
` $(window).unload(function() {
     alert( "Leaving this place..." );
  });`
```

These options are better than constantly polling to see which field is clicked and performing updates each time. From the documentation: *It is not possible to cancel the `unload` event with `.preventDefault()`. This event is available so that scripts can perform cleanup when the user leaves the page.*